# PHPUnit Mock Database Connection Class

Tags: php, mysql, mocking, phpunit, database-abstraction

I'm adding unit tests to legacy codes in a MVC framework. I have a model class called DbConnection that initiate all the database connection, it looks like this:

```
class DbConnection 
   function __construct()
   {
       mysql_connect(hardcoded)
   }
}
```

Every methods that needs database access would then call the DBConnection, like this:

```
function insertUser()
{
    $db = new DbConnection();
    $sql = "SELECT .....
    ....
 }
```

If I want to have the option of either connect to a different testing database or using a xml file as a mock database, how should I do it without refactor the code?

Comment: php-test-helpers has Intercepting Object Creation function which would work perfectly, but it cannot be installed on windows environment... [https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-test-helpers]

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: I know PDO or mysqli is the way to go, but I'm working with over 1 million lines of legacy code which still uses mysql extension... So far, my boss has no intention of refactor the old stuff, but he insists we do unit testing... Hence my problem and my question...

Comment: @forest2087 Did you find a solution or just give up?